# When are things not executed on the main thread in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I know to make UI updates you need to execute the updates on the main thread. I do that using

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:]
```

But at the moment I just simply add it when a UI update doesn't work, without understanding why.

How do you actually know which things are executed on the main thread and which things aren't? Are generally all callbacks and delegate functions on a side thread? What about functions that are executed when certain events are triggered, like button presses?

I would like to know a general rule when something isn't on the main thread, so that I don't have to wait for something to break first.

Comment: This question is way too general. Delegation and callbacks are implementation details and architecture patterns. You cannot make a blanket statement like All delegates are called on main thread. UITableViewDataSource is an example that calls its delegate on the main thread whereas NSURLSessionTaskDelegate is always called asynchronously. It depends where you are. All UI events will and should be main thread.

Comment: So how do you know which delegate is main thread and which is asynchronous? Can you look it up somewhere for each delegate?

Comment: all you can always go if([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:[NSThread mainThread]) but again it depends. You need to provide examples rather than a generalized question, where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: I'm not struggling anywhere in particular. I develop Apps and sometimes the UI doesn't change the way it should. Every time I realize it's because a specific callback updates the UI of which I didn't know it runs on a side thread. Now I wonder how I can know when using a new callback, delegate, etc. if it's running on a side thread or the main thread. Surely this must be documented somewhere? It can't be that everyone just waits for their code to break to realize it's on the wrong queue.

Comment: Like I said it depends what framework, but almost all UIKit frameworks will callback to the main thread. Networking and core data might not. Depends on the framework sometimes its documented sometimes its not but there is no website that will list all the frameworks and which ones call back to main thread etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, sounds like trial and error will be the quickest way then.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if you are running on main thread with [+isMainThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/isMainThread) method:

```
-(void)uiUpdateMethod
{
    if([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        //main just exec code
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            //exec code
        }];
    }
}
```

However as I understand you want to know exactly what methods are performing on background thread. So unfortunately this is quite complicated question and answer is framework documentation.